# How to capture a search term from a form and pass it to a method in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am learning rails online and have got as far as creating a simple site with some products in a products table with fields:

id

name

price

description

I have gone to the getbootstrap site and started pinching the code from this example -

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/jumbotron/

This page has a nice search box in the navbar at the top right. I now have it in my simple site and the container HTML currently looks like this:

```
<div class="container" >
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Shop</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Products</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

My problem is that all of the tutorials I see are creating simple forms using ERB to implement some sort of search functionality. like so:

```
<% form_tag projects_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

While I want to utilise this nicely rendered HTML form instead.

I don't know how to capture the search term and pass it to a method from my form. The ERB example uses the params hash to store the search term.

What I would like to implement is -

1 - Capture the name of a product entered in the search box

2 - Pass that string to a method in my model that queries the DB for first matching name

3 - gets the record id and uses it to redirect to the Show page with the id to display the item

I have found that setting the form action to "/" causes a click on the submit button to jump to the index method in my controller. From there I am sure I could utilise the model to query the underlying DB but I cannot seem to pass across the search term.

I do have a params hash at that point but it just seems to have a "controller" and an "action" member. Is there an attribute I can set that would add the value to this hash?

Thanks in advance

Brad

Comment: Bootstrap has nothing to do with your question(s). Post your current Rails code snippet for the task you are trying to accomplish. Otherwise, your question might get closed for being **too broad**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set an action to the form and a name to the field

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="/search" method="get">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search", name: "search>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Then define the method in a controller.

StaticPagesController

```
def search
  @search_term = params[:search]
end
```

And define your route in routes.rb

```
match '/search',  to: 'static_pages#search', via: 'get'
```

Comment: Many thanks Pablo, the name got me past the issue. Cheers :) I would like to accept this answer but I don't seem to have any method for doing so...

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts, *when you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community. (If you don't do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)*. You can also upvote :)